# Symfony Form Unit Test with Collections

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to make my firsts unit tests and functionnal tests with Symfony3 / PHPunit and I don't find solutions to my problem.

To be simple, I'm trying to Unit Test a form created to manage `Users` and `Groups` (provided by FOSUserBundle)

I followed the [steps of the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html) to test my form, and I already solved some issues concerning `getExtensions()`, etc... to be able to run my test without any error

Here is my `UserType.php` :

```
<?php

...

class UserType extends BaseCrudForm
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'label.username'))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'label' => 'label.email',
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Email()
                )
            ))
            ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'label.enabled', 'required' => false))
            ->add('groups', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\Group',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('avatarImageFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'label.avatar', 'required' => false))
        ;
    }

    ...

}
```

and my `UserTypeTest.php` (I left my tests into it) :

```
<?php

...

class UserTypeTest extends BaseTypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = array(
            'username' => 'nathalie_' . time(),
            'email' => 'nathalie_' . time() . '@portman.fr',
            'enabled' => true,
            'plainPassword' => 'pa$$word',

            ///// SOLUTION 1
            'groups' => array(
                $this->em->getRepository('AcmeAdminBundle:Group')->find(1)
            ),
            ///// SOLUTION 2
            'groups' => array(1),
        );

        $form = $this->factory->create(UserType::class);

        $user = User::fromArray($formData);

        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

        // dump($user, $form->getData());

        $this->assertEquals($user, $form->getData()); //Fails

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach(array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

### **Problem :**

The assert `$this->assertEquals($user, $form->getData());` fails, because of the collection `User::groups` that is not equal

#### Solution 1 is not working (see code above)

The collection of `$user` is ok, but the form data is empty

#### Solution 2 is not working neither (see code above)

The form data is ok, but the `$user` collection is instantiated with a simple `array(1)` (sees logic)

### Question

How could I instanciate correctly my object User and my form at the same time with the same informations (as it's described in the Symfony documentation a linked in top of this topic) ?

*Note: as I said I'm a newbie with Unit Tests, so don't hesitate to tell me if I miss the point*

#### Edit

Here is the `fromArray` function, implemented as a `Trait` in the User entity :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Traits;    

use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;

trait FromArrayTrait
{
    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return self
     */
    public static function fromArray(array $data)
    {
        $object = new self;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . Inflector::classify($key);

            if (method_exists($object, $method)) {
                call_user_func(array($object, $method), $value);
            }
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `User::fromArray` function? I guess you need to change how the groups are handled in there. Alternatively you can create you user with solution 1 and override the groups part of `$formData` with solution 2 before passing it to the submit function.

Comment: Hi ! Thx for your answer !
I will edit the post for the function, but yes it does not retrieve Groups by ID, it's just a simple function that try to call setters for attributes.
But I'm a little confused : Symfony's documentation show a "fromArray"" function but does not show it's code :/